# Magento 2 Add custom product attribute to 'Recently Ordered Items' section

Tags: magento2, customer, product-attribute, sales-order

I want to add custom product attribute say "flavor" next to product name in "Recently Ordered Items" section.

I checked the phtml to see where the data comes from. `lastOrderedItems().items` is the answer. 
To check further I opened last-ordered-items.js where it fetches data like this

```
this.lastOrderedItems = customerData.get('last-ordered-items');
```

Then I opened customer-data.js to check the get() function and I find this:

```
get: function (sectionName) {
            if (!this.data[sectionName]) {
                this.bind(sectionName);
            }

            return this.data[sectionName];
        },
```

My question is how do I debug further and know how it is actually fetching the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override Below file.

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/CustomerData/LastOrderedItems.php
```

In This file you can add additional attribute after line no :103. In example if i want to show Product Sku then i need to write below code.

```
'name' => $item->getName(),
'sku' => $item->getSku(),
```

Override below file also

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml
```

In this file , Write below code for showing Product Sku

```
<span data-bind="text: sku"></span>
```

At last , Just logout and login again in my account

Answer (score 0):

I added the flavor to the section like this.

Here is my file:

LastOrderedItems.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sejal\Sales\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

class LastOrderedItems extends \Magento\Sales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems
{
    /**
     * Limit of orders in side bar
     */
    const SIDEBAR_ORDER_LIMIT = 5;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
    */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * Init customer order for display on front
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initOrders()
    {
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();

        $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()])
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPage(1, 1);
        //TODO: add filter by current website
        $this->orders = $orders;
    }

    /**
     * Get list of last ordered products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getItems()
    {
        $items = [];
        $order = $this->getLastOrder();
        $limit = self::SIDEBAR_ORDER_LIMIT;

        if ($order) {
            $website = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            foreach ($order->getParentItemsRandomCollection($limit) as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct() && in_array($website, $item->getProduct()->getWebsiteIds())) {
                    $items[] = [
                        'id' => $item->getId(),
                        'name' => $item->getName(),
                        'url' => $item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(),
                        'flavor' => $this->getFlavours($item),
                        'is_saleable' => $this->isItemAvailableForReorder($item),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Check item product availability for reorder
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function isItemAvailableForReorder(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem)
    {
        try {
            $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
                $orderItem->getProduct()->getId(),
                $orderItem->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
            );
            return $stockItem->getIsInStock();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $noEntityException) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Last order getter
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order|void
     */
    protected function getLastOrder()
    {
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->initOrders();
        }
        foreach ($this->orders as $order) {
            return $order;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSectionData()
    {
        return ['items' => $this->getItems()];
    }

    /**
     * Flavors name
     *
     * @return Flavors name
    */
    public function getFlavours($item)
    { 
        $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $this->product->load($productId);
        $productFlavours = $this->product->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($this->product);         
        if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
            $productFlavours = '';
        }
        return $productFlavours;
    }
}
```